# In a JVM, what memory space does the stack memory goes to?

Tags: java, jvm

As I have read, a JVM has two memory spaces (in java 8), heap and metaspace.

We can specify the stack memory using `-Xss` flag (As I have read, default is 1MB in java 8). If the java program creates thousands of threads, the memory for stacks can be quite significant.

So, in what memory space (heap or metaspace) does the thread stacks reside?

Comment: The stack size is _per thread_; as such, this 1MB will only be eaten for each thread and no two threads share this space. After that, well, this is 2015 so OSes which do not do demand paging are dead or, at worst, dying.

Answer (score -1):

Java virtual machine memory is composed of regions. The stack region where variables and methods are stored and the heap space region where everything else is stored. The Java heap space is once again structured in different regions called generations and where an object is stored depends on how long the object lives.

> There is only one heap inside the JVM, and all threads share it. The
>   heap contains nothing but objects. There is no way to place a solitary
>   primitive type or object reference on the heap -- these things must be
>   part of an object. Arrays reside on the heap, including arrays of
>   primitive types, but in Java, arrays are objects too.
>
> Besides the Java stack and the heap, the other place data may reside
>   in the JVM is the method area, which contains all the class (or
>   static) variables used by the program. The method area is similar to
>   the stack in that it contains only primitive types and object
>   references. Unlike the stack, however, the class variables in the
>   method area are shared by all threads.

**There is only one heap inside the JVM, and all threads share it.** for detailed info keep reading in [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html)

Comment: I don't mind a downvote but, I definitely mind not knowing the reason for a downvote. If I made a mistake, tell me the reason so that I avoid repeating it in the future.

Comment: your answer is not clear and does not directly answer my question. You say there is a stack region but google search `Java stack region` does not give any results proving it. Also, method code does not reside on stack, rather in metaspace. Also, each thread gets its own stack memory, but you have not specified whether they go in same `region` you mentioned. Also you have mentioned in bolded text (implying it answers my specific question) that all threads share the same heap. But, that doesn't answer my question. (My question is, which region the stack of each thread resides)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, I do admit that java stack region is not valid and it should be java stack memory, regions only applies to heap. I wrote the answer with java 7 in mind.